# Javascript long polling event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, long-polling

I have long-polling specific problem. I would like to be able to attach event listener to document, that checks for successful long-polling request and gives me json results as return of callback function. Is it possible with jquery or pure js? The assumption is that I cannot modify any js code, only add event handler.

Comment: If you can't change any JS code, It's going to be really hard to do with jQuery or pure JS ?

Comment: I meant that I would like to add function to existing code, without any changes.

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried up until now? Also, jQuery is written in JS, which means that everything that is possible with jQuery is also possible with vanilla JS :)

Comment: Are you talking about Ajax request?

Comment: no, Long Polling one

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's ajaxComplete() method, that listens for any XHR (ajax requests) coming back. http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this, it is not AJAX request, but long-polling

Comment: What do you mean? What's the code that triggers the call?

Comment: I will be probably taken unseriously but I cannot find this in minified code, I tried by without success. All I can see is that in chrome developer tools in xhr tab there are get requests constantly being made every 40ms.

Comment: So, if they are XHR request, why isn't my answer relevant?

Comment: I am not sure, it just didn't work. I have found the solution by overriding attribute of XMLHttpRequest.prototype.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this problem, by overriding attribute of XMLHttpRequest.prototype.